# How to delete subarrays but keep their contents in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array of objects:

```
const pages = [
  {
    posts: {
      pageInfo: { 
        hasNextPage: true 
      },
      edges: [
        { id: 1 },
        { id: 2 }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    posts: {
      pageInfo: { 
        hasNextPage: true 
      },
      edges: [
        { id: 3 },
        { id: 4 }
      ]
    }
  },
]
```

I need to keep only the content of the `edges` subarrays, like this:

```
const postsOnly = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 4 }
]
```

Closest I've come is:

```
const postsOnly = pages.map( ( { posts } ) =>  posts.edges )
```

But this leaves me with a subarray for every original `posts` object, like this:

```
const postsOnly = [
  [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 }
  ],
  [
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 4 }
  ]
]
```

How can I delete these subarrays but keep their contents?

Comment: `const postsOnly = pages.flatMap( ( { posts } ) =>  posts.edges ) `

Comment: This is a wrong syntax I guess

Comment: @MaheerAli Why? https://wandbox.org/permlink/cpnHlHBXEzfnuscC

Comment: @ThomasSablik Hey, thanks! If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as the right answer.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I am not saying this to you. I am saying that the data OP showed contains duplicate keys(Its not wrong syntax but wrong data and you never duplicate keys like that)

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for all the answers but I realized the original example was wrong as in I had two different "posts" objects in the parent array (I've fixed it now), so some answers may have been misled by that. Anyway, @ThomasSablik's answer worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `map(...).flat()` or `flatMap(...)` to flatten the result

```js
const pages = [
  {
    posts: {
      pageInfo: { 
        hasNextPage: true 
      },
      edges: [
        { id: 1 },
        { id: 2 }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    posts: {
      pageInfo: { 
        hasNextPage: true 
      },
      edges: [
        { id: 3 },
        { id: 4 }
      ]
    }
  },
];

const postsOnly = pages.map( ( { posts } ) =>  posts.edges );
const postsOnly2 = pages.flatMap( ( { posts } ) =>  posts.edges );
const postsOnly3 = pages.map( ( { posts } ) =>  posts.edges ).flat();

console.log(postsOnly);
/* Output: 
[ [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 } ], [ { id: 3 }, { id: 4 } ] ]
*/
console.log(postsOnly2);
/* Output:
[ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 } ]
*/
console.log(postsOnly3);
/* Output:
[ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 } ]
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const pages = [{
  posts: {
    pageInfo: { 
      hasNextPage: true 
    },
    edges: [
      { id: 1 },
      { id: 2 }
    ]
  }},
  {
  posts: {
    pageInfo: { 
      hasNextPage: false 
    },
    edges: [
      { id: 3 },
      { id: 4 }
    ]
  },
}];

const postsOnly = pages.map( ( { posts } ) =>  posts.edges).flat();
console.log(postsOnly);
```

What you are doing it's ok, you are just missing a `.flat()`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: The data you are using is not that OP posted. See its a single object in the whole array. Maybe point it out too

Comment: You are right, I figured out that it's wrong when I copy/pasted it. Will do it.